# If i call Insert method from C i want to get output "Now in Class B", But actually i get "Now in Class C" why? how can it be solved?

Tags: java, inheritance, extends

```
public Interface D{

    public abstract String  Joo();
    public abstract String Foo();
    public bean Tem(){

     Joo();
    }
}
 public abstract Class A{

    protected abstract String  Joo();
    protected abstract String Foo();
    protected bean Tem(){

      Joo();
    }
 }


 public Class B extends A impliments D{
 protected String Joo(){
    System.out.println("Now in class B");
    }
 protected String Foo(){
    super.Tem();
    }
}

public Class C extends B{

    protected String Joo(){
    System.out.println("Now in class C");
  }
 protected String Foo(){
   super.Tem();
   }
 public void Insert(){
 super.Foo();
  }

}
```

If i call Insert method from C i want to get output "Now in Class B", But actually i get "Now in Class C" why?
how can it be solved?
Also when calling foo method in Class C ,i want output "Now in Class C".

Comment: But that output would be wrong. You are not in class B, but in class C. Perhaps the real question is, WHY you want to do that? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: You can not get it using instance of class C, either you will have to call `super.Joo()` in your Joo method of class C or else use instance of class B.

Comment: What programming language is that code supposed to be? You have tagged your question with `java` but it only slightly resembles the Java syntax. I doubt that you get the described output with *that*. And why did you tag it with `spring-mvc`?

Comment: actually i'm doing this in java and using springMvc.

Comment: i created an instance of class B. then i called Foo().  B obj=new B();    obj.Foo();

Answer (score 0):

Calling

```
C c = new C();
c.Insert();
```

calls `Foo()` from `B`, which calls `Tem()` from `A`. Due to late binding, `Joo()` will call the `Joo` method from the most derived class, i.e. `C`.

Whether you specify `super` when calling `Tem` or not, you'll end up calling `C`'s `Joo` method from an instance of `C`, as long as this method is overridden there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't - at least not without a refactor.

Here's you code cleaned up so it is clearer. Note that the `@Override` indicates that this method overrides an inherited method.

```
public abstract class A {

    protected abstract String Joo();

    protected abstract String Foo();

    protected String Tem() {

        return Joo();
    }
}

public class B extends A {

    @Override
    protected String Joo() {
        System.out.println("Now in class B");
        return "From B";
    }

    @Override
    protected String Foo() {
        return super.Tem();
    }
}

public class C extends B {

    @Override
    protected String Joo() {
        System.out.println("Now in class C");
        return "From C";
    }

    @Override
    protected String Foo() {
        return super.Tem();
    }

    public void Insert() {
        super.Foo();
    }

}

public void test() {
    C c = new C();
    // Valid - Prints Now in class C
    c.Insert();
    // Valid - Prints Now in class C
    c.Foo();
}
```

See how `Insert` on a `C` calls `B.Foo` which calls `A.Tem` which calls `Joo`. `A.Joo` is implemented in `B` but **overriden** in `C` so the final result is `C.Joo`.